# Django dynamic way to display formfields by context

Tags: javascript, python, django, forms, django-forms

I am pretty much a long time beginner with Django, so sorry for this question if it is too broad, misplaced or even obvious.

I have read several posts on here, and a few examples such as [this](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/nov/09/dynamic-forms/) or [this](http://www.slideshare.net/kingkilr/forms-getting-your-moneys-worth), but none describe achieving what I need to do.

Imagine I have the form below for submitting a project and I want to display fields and add them or reveal them in the form client side, but only if certain input criteria are met in the form - eg. if the project to be submitted is part of a series of projects (is_project_series), then I might want to display a number of form fields for eg. how many projects should be in the series or how they should be named or numbered, maybe even generate further dynamic input based on the input of these dynamic fields also - otherwise by default the project form might only display the most simple fields for 'projectname', 'project_format' etc. and the boolean for 'is_project_series' which would reveal the hidden fields dynamically when True.

I was wondering what skilled Django users do to get this sort of functionality and if there are any built-in tools to support it? or if it's just a matter of javascript and hidden fields.

If anybody can provide an example based on a simple models/forms such as this.

Models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    projectname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Forms.py

```
class ProjectCreateForm(ModelForm):
    ''' Project CREATE form'''
    project_format = forms.TypedChoiceField(
        label = "Project Format",
        choices = ((1, "HD"), (0, "SD")),
        coerce = lambda x: bool(int(x)),
        widget = forms.RadioSelect,
        initial = '1',
        required = True,)

    is_project_series = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput, default=False)

    *A number of extra form fields here based on if 'is_project_series' is defined as True or False *

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProjectCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('project_submit', 'Done')) # class and label
        self.fields['programme'] = ProgrammeChoiceFieldLong(Redaktion.objects.all().order_by('usercode').exclude(active=False))

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['programme','projectname','is_project_series']
```

Answer (score 0):

the current model instance is passed to **init** so you can do your if statement there:

```
def __init__(self, instance=None, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ProjectCreateForm, self).__init__(instance=instance, *args, **kwargs)
    if instance and instance.is_project_series:
        # do stuff
```

Comment: True, but doesn't __init__ only execute when the form is instantiated? So I would have to send an is_project_series *arg posted to the first instance of the form. I want to avoid posting back and forward to the server and do it all dynamically in the form. I'll use this - http://jsfiddle.net/QAaHP/16/